How can I translate the property for a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ to a solution in the endomorphism ring
Let $E$ be defined by $y^2+y=x^3+x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. It is known, that $\# E(\mathbb{F}_2)=5$, so $E$ is supersingular and $\phi_2^2 + 2\phi_2+2=0$.
Show that $\phi_2^4=-4$. (This is exercise 5.12 a) in Elliptic Curves by Washington)
I had much struggle with this exercise and found this  post, basically concerning the same question.
In the answer Asvin suggested, that one can prove this by showing, that every solution of the equation $x^2+2x+2=0$ has this property.
I basically computed the solutions $\mp1\pm i$ and then it is easy to see that indeed, the fourth power of every solution equals $-4$. However, for me it is not clear how this proves the claim. I mean I explicitly computed the solutions of this equation in $\mathbb{C}$, and I have no idea how the fact that the fourth power of these solutions equal $-4$ should transfer to the fact that the frobenius endomorphism also has this property.
The proof for $\phi_2^2+2\phi_2+2=0$ (resp. the general case) uses the cayley-hamilton theorem, does this theorem by any means imply the answer to my question?
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to understand this, or give an alternative solution.

This has nothing to do with $\mathbb C$. If $x$ is an element in a ring satisfying $x^2+2x+2 = 0$, then also
$$
x^4 + 4 = (x^2+2x+2)\cdot (x^2-2x+2) = 0
$$
in that ring.

Sometimes the solutions are so easy, but you still do not recognize it. Thank you very much!
